# Getting the position of controls in a windows store app in C#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I want to fetch the positions of controls within a page in windows store apps in pixels.
It would be nice to be able to do it for an arbitrary control, however for the moment just figuring out how to do it for a button would be fine!

I've tried looking at margins, but they seem to often have no relation to the actual position when mechanisms like `Grid.Row="x"` or `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` are used in the Xaml or set programatically. I would need this method to work whatever the method of positioning the control is.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I'm testing by setting up a UI:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>            
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>            
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="test" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="test"/>
</Grid>
```

and then modifying the 'Grid.Column', 'Grid.Row' and Alignment characteristics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get position of control using transform object.

```
<Button x:Name="btn" Content="Button" Margin="131,339,0,391" />

void BlankPage4_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var trans = test.TransformToVisual(null);
    var point = trans.TransformPoint(new Windows.Foundation.Point());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however, using only alignment and grid positioning as above in my edit, your method yielded the point (0,0).

Comment: See updated answer. You need to write code in `Loaded` event rather than `OnNavigatedTo`. I tried your XAML and I am getting (654,365) in 1366 x 768 resoluion.

Comment: Cheers, thanks that worked!
I had in fact tried this earlier, the problem is that I was doing it before the page was fully loaded, so I was always getting (0,0) as the position.